# WooCommerce Custom Shipping Methods Removing Each Other

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created 2 basic shipping methods in 2 different plugins, each plugin are below, one is Royal Mail the other is Courier. They both show up in the drop down in the shipping zone:

[image]

I can then add say Royal Mail to the zone, but if i now come to add Courier as well, Royal Mail disappears and vice versa, it's only letting me add one of my custom methods at a time and i'm stumped as to why.

The next problem is, when i delete one of my custom methods and hit save, i'm getting this fatal error and it doesn't remove, as far as i can see both of these classes are done correctly to the point they are at:

> [14-Dec-2021 13:54:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a
> member function get_instance_option_key() on bool in
> /Volumes/Work/project/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php:2923

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', function() : void {

    /**
     * Class Utterly_Courier_Shipping_Method
     */
    class Utterly_Courier_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method
    {

        /**
         * Utterly_Royal_Mail_Shipping_Method constructor.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->id = 'utterly_courier';
            $this->method_title = 'Courier delivery (Tracked & Signed)';
            $this->method_description = 'Shipping via Courier';


            $this->supports = [
                'shipping-zones'
            ];

            $this->init();

            $this->enabled = 'yes';
            $this->title = 'Courier delivery (Tracked & Signed)';
        }


        /**
         *
         */
        public function init() : void
        {
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        public function init_form_fields() : void
        {
            parent::init_form_fields();
        }

        /**
         * @param array $package
         */
        public function calculate_shipping($package = [])
        {
            $rate = array(
                'id' => $this->id,
                'label' => $this->title,
                'cost' => 10
            );

            $this->add_rate( $rate );
        }
    }
});


add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', function( array $methods ) : array {
    $methods['utterly_courier'] = 'Utterly_Courier_Shipping_Method';

    return $methods;
});


add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', function() : void {

    /**
     * Class Utterly_Royal_Mail_Shipping_Method
     */
    class Utterly_Royal_Mail_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method
    {

        /**
         * Utterly_Royal_Mail_Shipping_Method constructor.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->id = 'utterly_royal_mail';
            $this->method_title = 'Royal Mail 1st Class (Tracked)';
            $this->method_description = 'Shipping via Royal Mail';


            $this->supports = [
                'shipping-zones'
            ];

            $this->init();

            $this->enabled = 'yes';
            $this->title = 'Royal Mail 1st Class (Tracked)';
        }


        /**
         *
         */
        public function init() : void
        {
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, [ $this, 'process_admin_options' ] );
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        public function init_form_fields() : void
        {
            parent::init_form_fields();
        }

        /**
         * @param array $package
         */
        public function calculate_shipping($package = [])
        {
            $rate = array(
                'id' => $this->id,
                'label' => $this->title,
                'cost' => 10
            );

            $this->add_rate( $rate );
        }
    }



});


add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', function( array $methods ) : array {
    $methods['utterly_royal_mail'] = 'Utterly_Royal_Mail_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
});
```

Comment: You are running same "function" for both shipping methods which overrides. But you see them as 2 bcs of your $methods array. Here you can see example how to register each method - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

Comment: Are you talking about on the action? They are closures, they aren't using the same function they are both 2 separate closures. Also that tutorial you sent even if i copy the entire lot of the code it doesn't work, the methods don't even show up.

Comment: Ok so it does show on the checkout when i have no methods in the zone set, but, now if i copy that same tutorial code and rename the functions and class so there are 2 different ones , only 1 of them works.